# How cassandra.consistent.rangemovement helps in adding more than one node to c* cluster

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

How cassandra.consistent.rangemovement=false(as suggested at https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html) helps in adding multiple nodes at a time to a existing cassandra cluster ?

Is the above way is better approach or auto_bootstrap:false is better approach to add more than one node at a time?

Comment: I don't understand fully but I found those: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.cassandra.user/46434 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2434. I hope this will help